# (R) How can a bigger expression be written by combining shorter variable expressions?

Tags: r, expression

Brief introduction, I have multiple data file that can be fitted by models based in mathematical equations that are a combination (by sum, mutiplication, etc...) of other shorter mathematical equations.

As an example I have three short equations:

```
expression1 <- exp(x)
expression2 <- exp(x^2)
expression3 <- exp(1/x)
```

Because each data file has it's own bigger expression that produce a better fit, I want to be able to generate these larger expressions as a combitaion of the shorter expressions.

What I want is to be able to write something like this:

`expression1(1) + expression1(2) * expression2(3) + expression2(1)`

And get:

`x1 + x2 * x3^2 + 1/x1`

Later I will use this larger equations to find the values x1, x2, x3 that better fits one data file.

Comment: `exp` is the exponential function, so your code above doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Presumably you meant expression rather than exp.  Making that change we define e1, e2, e3 and e.  esub is a function which replaces a variable name with another in an expression.  gsubfn in the package of the same name is like gsub except the second argument can be a function   (possibly expressed using formula notation as we do here) which takes the capture groups in the pattern as arguments and replaces the entire pattern with the output of the function.  We deparse e, use gsubfn and parse it back.

```
library(gsubfn)

e1 <- expression(x)
e2 <- expression(x^2)
e3 <- expression(1/x)
e <- expression(e1(1) + e1(2) * e2(3) + e2(1))

esub <- function(expr, env) do.call("substitute", list(expr, env))
g <- gsubfn("(\\w+)[(](\\w+)[)]", 
  ~ deparse(esub(get(x)[[1]], list(x = as.name(paste0("x", y))))), 
  deparse(e))
parse(text = g)[[1]]
## expression(x1 + x2 * x3^2 + x1^2)
```

**2)** If it were desired to use strings instead of expressions it is even shorter:

```
library(gsubfn)

s1 <- "x"
s2 <- "x^2"
s3 <- "1/x"
s <- "s1(1) + s1(2) * s2(3) + s2(1)"

gsubfn("(\\w+)[(](\\w+)[)]", x + y ~ gsub("\\bx\\b", paste0("x", y), get(x)), s)
## [1] "x1 + x2 * x3^2 + x1^2"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works perfectly, there are still some details of the code you wrote that I need to understand better (no need to explain it the answer is clear and very useful) And yes, I meant expression instead of exp, it was a mistake when writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

`exp` is the exponential function, so your code doesn't do what you think it does. To get something like this to work probably needs the creation of a new S3 class with `print` and `Ops` methods:

```r
make_exp <- function(expr) {
  expr <- match.call()$expr
  function(x) structure(list(val = do.call(substitute, list(expr))), 
                        class = "ex")
}

print.ex <- function(x, ...) print(x$val)

Ops.ex <- function(e1, e2) structure(list(val = call(.Generic, e1$val, e2$val)),
                                      class = "ex")
```

This allows

```
expression1 <- make_exp(x)
expression2 <- make_exp(x^2)
expression3 <- make_exp(1/x)

expression1(x1) + expression2(x2) * expression3(x3)
#> x1 + x2^2 * (1/x3)
```